# Cassandra creates multiple connections and not release

Tags: python, cassandra

I am using Python Cassandra-Driver 3.15.1

I have a script that runs some multiproc.

The problem is that for some reason, the connection is not properly released after calling close_connection (get_connection -> run CQL -> close_connection -> then to the end call close_cluster. This results to over hundreds of connections/sessions stay open

Any hints on where to look for the issue is very much appreciated.

```
def get_connection(self, timeout = 600):
    self.session = Cluster([self.host]).connect()
    self.session.default_timeout = timeout
    return self.session

def close_connection(self, conn):
    return conn.shutdown()

def close_cluster_connection(self):
    return self.cluster.shutdown()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `Cluster` object should be explicitly shutdown when finished, but that's not possible here because you aren't holding on to the instance created by `Cluster([self.host])` in `get_connection`.

`close_cluster_connection` references a `self.cluster`. If that's already instantiated and the cluster instance you want to use, `get_connection` should look like this.

```
def get_connection(self, timeout = 600):
    self.session = self.cluster.connect()
    self.session.default_timeout = timeout
    return self.session
```

If you can't use `self.cluster` there, you have to find a way to keep track of your `Cluster` instances and shut them down when you're done.

Comment: Thanks for the hints @falcojr. This did help to resolve 50% of the issue. I applied another hack by implementing a destructor which resolved the rest 50% of the issue. Now all the connections are closed properly

Comment: @tudou can you share the code snippet of your destructor?